# Incorrect values when summing values in a column according to other 3 columns

Tags: dplyr, sum, tidyverse, summarize

I am working on the output file from phyloseq object. I calculated the rel.abundance and extracted the columns I am interested in as follows:
this is how I calculate the rel_abund

```
dat <- read_excel("selected_data.xlsx")%>% group_by(OTU)%>% mutate(rel_abund = Abundance/sum(Abundance))
dat
```

OTU     Abundance   SampleID    Genotype   rel_abund
                            
ASV2     4988        P35        genotype1      0.2801617614
ASV4     3894     1P-GH-R2      genotype2      0.9660133962
ASV7     3681       P53         genotype1      0.5047305636
ASV3     2149       P16         genotype4      0.3943842907

Then I need to calculate the summed relative abundance of each ASV in each genotype. Each genotype is represented by 1-5 samples, and I have 44 ASVs of 2,464 rows according to their occurrences in samples

To display each ASV along with its rel_abund across genotypes including sampleIDs, I tried this

```
dat %>%
  count(OTU, SampleID, rel_abund, Genotype) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = SampleID, values_from = n)
```

results in

OTU    rel_abund    Genotype      1P-R1      1P-R2     P1    .......
                             
ASV1    0.0000000000 genotype11      1        1        NA   NA  NA  NA  NA
ASV1    0.0000000000  genotype2     NA        NA        1    NA NA  NA  NA

Then,

```
dat %>%
  group_by(OTU, Genotype) %>%
  summarize(Summed_rel_abund = sum(rel_abund >= 0, na.rm = TRUE))
```

gives:

OTU         Genotype  Summed_rel_abund
                 
ASV1         genotype1       1
ASV1         genotype3       3
ASV1         genotype2       1
ASV1         genotype5       3
ASV1         genotype6       2
ASV10        genotype7       5
ASV10        genotype8       5

I do not how the sum is integers and the summed values are decimal fractions. I doubt the last step and I need a correction, please!
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, `sum(rel_abund >= 0)` is summing the `TRUE` values of the `>= 0` test, counting each as 1, therefore effectively just counting. To sum the values where the value >= 0 try `sum(rel_abund[rel_abund >= 0], na.rm = TRUE)`:

```r
dat %>%
  group_by(OTU, Genotype) %>%
  summarize(Summed_rel_abund = sum(rel_abund[rel_abund >= 0], na.rm = TRUE)) 

#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#> # Groups:   OTU [4]
#>   OTU   Genotype  Summed_rel_abund
#>   <chr> <chr>                <dbl>
#> 1 ASV2  genotype1            0.280
#> 2 ASV3  genotype4            0.394
#> 3 ASV4  genotype2            0.966
#> 4 ASV7  genotype1            0.505
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Yes, it works now. Much thanks! I have another question, now I exported the dataframe as spreadsheet like this

Comment: Yes, it works now. Much thanks! I have another question, now I exported the dataframe as spreadsheet like this OTU MaizeGenotype Summed_rel_abund
ASV1 genotype1  0.065788097479343
ASV1 genotype2 0.008785691873235
ASV1 genotype  0.034306034933584
ASV1 genotype3 0.185963811316808
ASV1 genotype4 0.176027612174459
and so on for each ASV, however, I need to display this as ASVs as unique rownames, and genotypes as unique colnames where each numeric value will be displayed in parallel to each corresponding genotype (as row). Any help here, please? Much thanks!

Comment: Hi Eman, does adding `pivot_wider(OTU, names_from = Genotype, values_from = Summed_rel_abund)` to the above code get you the output you are looking for?

Comment: Great! All the best with next steps. Do mark question as completed if you get a chance.